# How to ease/reduce surface roughness caused by ion sputtering?

Tags: vacuum, metals, microscopy, nanoscience

I want to investigate the electron emission of samples under electron bombardment.

Experts will know that surface condition plays a huge role in the emission rate and some other properties (e.g. max energy). Therefore, these experiments are done in UHV, and a lot of surface treatments going on, like ion-sputtering.

However, the ion-sputtering changes the surface condition, i.e. creating a rougher surface. Is there a follow-up process to ease, reduce the roughness caused by ion sputtering?

Note: I guess sample annealing can help for re-crystallization, but I am not sure. Help needed!

Comment: Changes to surface under sputtering cover quite a large range, depending on the surface material and orientation, original roughness, ion species/energy/incident angle, and probably a variety of other things I've forgotten. Under some conditions the surface roughens, under others it can get smoother. There often is literature out there (back to the 1970's), and experimentation in your particular equipment will be needed.

Comment: Hi @JonCuster. Let say we have Ar+ ions and beam energy is 1-3 keV, and the material is tungsten. Can you name a few processes then I can look for them in the literature?

Comment: Maybe start at, say, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022311517307262 and dive into the references? Wasn't really my area at the time...